# Scientists in Antarctica dig up a Neanderthal and impregnate a woman with its DNA

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

SF book where a scientist digs up a Neanderthal and take the DNA from it and use it to impregnate a woman trying to recreate a Neanderthal. However when she is impregnated the twins inside her grow really fast and rip out of her; they are aliens named Kane and Abel and want to destroy the planet.

The cover of the book has a skull underneath the ice and a human standing over it. The aliens are very humanoid like which is why they thought it was a Neanderthal.

To be honest I don't know much else my coworker told me about this book and I've been trying to find it ever since and have not come close to it me and three other people tried I know it was also made before 1990.